# Why does the Snap7 library for Python work inside the terminal but not when I try to use it in PyCharm or another IDE?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, snap7

So I've been trying to install the snap7 library on a Raspberry Pi 4(buster) in order to work with it in python. However, it seems that when I try to run some commands inside the terminal:

```
python3
import snap7
plc = snap7.client.Client()
```

everything works fine.(it also works if I try to create a script in nano for example)

When I try to run the same script inside PyCharm I get an error saying that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snap7'".
Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Comment: pip3 install python-snap7

Comment: i've already installed it, tried running it again, it wasn't successful

Comment: Have you tried installing in the PyCharm terminal emulator? What packages *do* import for you in your IDE(s)?

Comment: I've installed PyCharm and I have managed to import it there and I can write some code using the library so I guess it's ok now